# How to compute the total in a two dimensional table?

Tags: helper, cobol

I'm still new to COBOL and learning about two dimensional tables. Here I'm having difficulty with how to accumulate the total of the two values in rows SOPHOMORE (1,1) = 100 for BSIT and (2,1) = 200 for BSCS with a total of 300.

The input file is: 100200300400500600200300

[image: Output File Display]

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TWODIME.
  *AUTHOR..
  *INSTALLATION. MANDALUYONG CITY.
  *DATE-WRITTEN. SEPTEMBER 9, 2019.
  *DATE-COMPILED. SEPTEMBER 10, 2019.
  *SECURITY. .
  *REMARKS.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SOURCE-COMPUTER. ANGELO-PC.
   OBJECT-COMPUTER. ANGELO-PC.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT INFILE ASSIGN TO 'VALSTUD.TXT'.
       SELECT OUTFILE ASSIGN TO 'VALOUT.TXT'.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD INFILE
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
       DATA RECORD IS INREC.
   01 INREC.
       02 YEAR OCCURS 4 TIMES.
            03 COURSE OCCURS 2 TIMES PIC 999.
       02 TOTALBA PIC 9(5)V99.
   FD OUTFILE
       LABEL RECORD IS OMITTED
       DATA RECORD IS OUTREC.
   01  OUTREC.
       02 FILLER PIC X(80).
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  I PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  J PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  EOFSW PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  TYEAR.
       02 TS PIC 9999 OCCURS 4 TIMES.
   01  HEAD-1.
       02 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(23) VALUE 'POLYTECHNIC UNIVERSITY '.
       02 FILLER PIC X(18) VALUE 'OF THE PHILIPPINES'.
   01  HEAD-2.
       02 FILLER PIC X(32) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE 'STA. MESA,'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE ' MANILA'.
   01  HEAD-3.
       02 FILLER PIC X(31) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE 'STUDENT'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(11) VALUE ' POPULATION'.
   01  SUB-1.
       02 FILLER PIC X(3) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE 'YEAR LEVEL'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(27) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLE PIC X(6) VALUE 'COURSE'.
   01  SUB-2.
       02 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(4) VALUE 'BSCS'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(4) VALUE 'BSIT'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(5) VALUE 'TOTAL'.
   01  DETAILS.
       02 FILLER PIC X(5) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-YEAR PIC X(9).
            02 FILLER PIC X(6) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-TAP OCCURS 2 TIMES.
           03 P-CTR PIC 999.
                   03 FILLER PIC X(17) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-TSTUDYEAR PIC 99,999.
   01  TOTAL-1.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01 SCRE.
       02 BLANK SCREEN.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-RTN.
       PERFORM INIT-RTN THRU INIT-RTN-END.
       PERFORM PROCESS-RTN UNTIL EOFSW = 1.
       PERFORM FINISH-RTN.
       STOP RUN.
   INIT-RTN. 
       OPEN INPUT INFILE, OUTPUT OUTFILE.
       READ INFILE AT END PERFORM END-RTN.
       PERFORM HEADING-RTN.
   INIT-RTN-END.
   END-RTN.
       MOVE 1 TO EOFSW.
       DISPLAY 'EMPTY FILE' LINE 3 COLUMN 20.
   HEADING-RTN.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-1 AFTER PAGE.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-2 AFTER 1.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-3 AFTER 3.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM SUB-1 AFTER 2.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM SUB-2 AFTER 1.
   PROCESS-RTN.
       DISPLAY SCRE.
       PERFORM ADD-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL I > 4 AFTER J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL 
       J > 2.
       PERFORM MOVE-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       I > 4.
       READ INFILE AT END MOVE 1 TO EOFSW.
   ADD-RTN.
       ADD COURSE ( I , J ) TO TS ( I ).
   MOVE-RTN.
       IF I = 1 MOVE 'FRESHMEN' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
       IF I = 2 MOVE 'SOPHOMORE' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
       IF I = 3 MOVE 'JUNIOR' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A. 
       IF I = 4 MOVE 'SENIOR' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
   A.
       PERFORM MOVE2-RTN VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       J > 2.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM DETAILS AFTER 1.
   MOVE2-RTN.
          MOVE TS ( I ) TO P-TSTUDYEAR.
       MOVE COURSE ( I , J ) TO P-TAP ( J ).
   FINISH-RTN.
       CLOSE INFILE, OUTFILE.
       DISPLAY 'OWARI DA!' LINE 5 COLUMN 20.
```

Comment: Please make clearer what your actual question is. You have a lot of more-or-less-structured code without any comment that reads a file and writes an output file. I assume you want to calculate something (you do have an `ADD` in there) and something is unexpected...

Answer (score 0):

I found three problems:

1. The sample data did not contain data for `TOATLBA`, though unused. I added seven zeros to the test data.
2. The item `01 TOTAL-1.` had no `PICTURE` clause. I made it a comment.
3. `TS ( I )` was not zero before adding the values. I added code to zero the data using your style.

---

[image: Displayed Output]

---

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TWODIME.
  *AUTHOR..
  *INSTALLATION. MANDALUYONG CITY.
  *DATE-WRITTEN. SEPTEMBER 9, 2019.
  *DATE-COMPILED. SEPTEMBER 10, 2019.
  *SECURITY.
  *REMARKS.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SOURCE-COMPUTER. ANGELO-PC.
   OBJECT-COMPUTER. ANGELO-PC.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT INFILE ASSIGN TO 'VALSTUD.TXT'.
       SELECT OUTFILE ASSIGN TO 'VALOUT.TXT'.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD INFILE
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
       DATA RECORD IS INREC.
   01 INREC.
       02 YEAR OCCURS 4 TIMES.
            03 COURSE OCCURS 2 TIMES PIC 999.
       02 TOTALBA PIC 9(5)V99.
   FD OUTFILE
       LABEL RECORD IS OMITTED
       DATA RECORD IS OUTREC.
   01  OUTREC.
       02 FILLER PIC X(80).
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  I PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  J PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  EOFSW PIC 9 VALUE IS 0.
   01  TYEAR.
       02 TS PIC 9999 OCCURS 4 TIMES.
   01  HEAD-1.
       02 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(23) VALUE 'POLYTECHNIC UNIVERSITY '.
       02 FILLER PIC X(18) VALUE 'OF THE PHILIPPINES'.
   01  HEAD-2.
       02 FILLER PIC X(32) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE 'STA. MESA,'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE ' MANILA'.
   01  HEAD-3.
       02 FILLER PIC X(31) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE 'STUDENT'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(11) VALUE ' POPULATION'.
   01  SUB-1.
       02 FILLER PIC X(3) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE 'YEAR LEVEL'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(27) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLE PIC X(6) VALUE 'COURSE'.
   01  SUB-2.
       02 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(4) VALUE 'BSCS'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(4) VALUE 'BSIT'.
       02 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE SPACE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(5) VALUE 'TOTAL'.
   01  DETAILS.
       02 FILLER PIC X(5) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-YEAR PIC X(9).
            02 FILLER PIC X(6) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-TAP OCCURS 2 TIMES.
           03 P-CTR PIC 999.
                   03 FILLER PIC X(17) VALUE SPACE.
       02 P-TSTUDYEAR PIC 99,999.
  *01  TOTAL-1.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01 SCRE.
       02 BLANK SCREEN.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-RTN.
       PERFORM INIT-RTN THRU INIT-RTN-END.
       PERFORM PROCESS-RTN UNTIL EOFSW = 1.
       PERFORM FINISH-RTN.
       STOP RUN.
   INIT-RTN. 
       OPEN INPUT INFILE, OUTPUT OUTFILE.
       READ INFILE AT END PERFORM END-RTN.
       PERFORM HEADING-RTN.
   INIT-RTN-END.
   END-RTN.
       MOVE 1 TO EOFSW.
       DISPLAY 'EMPTY FILE' LINE 3 COLUMN 20.
   HEADING-RTN.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-1 AFTER PAGE.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-2 AFTER 1.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM HEAD-3 AFTER 3.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM SUB-1 AFTER 2.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM SUB-2 AFTER 1.
   PROCESS-RTN.
       DISPLAY SCRE.
       PERFORM ZERO-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL I > 4.
       PERFORM ADD-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL I > 4 AFTER J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       J > 2.
       PERFORM MOVE-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       I > 4.
       READ INFILE AT END MOVE 1 TO EOFSW.
   ZERO-RTN.
       MOVE ZERO TO TS ( I ).
   ADD-RTN.
       ADD COURSE ( I , J ) TO TS ( I ).
   MOVE-RTN.
       IF I = 1 MOVE 'FRESHMEN' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
       IF I = 2 MOVE 'SOPHOMORE' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
       IF I = 3 MOVE 'JUNIOR' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A. 
       IF I = 4 MOVE 'SENIOR' TO P-YEAR PERFORM A.
   A.
       PERFORM MOVE2-RTN VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       J > 2.
       WRITE OUTREC FROM DETAILS AFTER 1.
   MOVE2-RTN.
          MOVE TS ( I ) TO P-TSTUDYEAR.
       MOVE COURSE ( I , J ) TO P-TAP ( J ).
   FINISH-RTN.
       CLOSE INFILE, OUTFILE.
       DISPLAY 'OWARI DA!' LINE 5 COLUMN 20.
```

---

Note that `MOVE-RTN` is inefficient. It would be better to place the text values in a table and move only the entry `( I ) TO P-YEAR`.

Also `MOVE TS ( I ) TO P-TSTUDYEAR.` is done twice. The statement could be moved to before `WRITE OUTREC ...`.

Comment: ohh i see Thank you very much! i change the 02 TS PIC 9999 OCCURS 4 TIMES and added a VALUE ZERO on it and it works the total, how about if i will total per column of BSIT and BSCS, i put the  PERFORM MOVE-RTN VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
       I > 4. to the FINISH-RTN. will i add another table to add per column of BSIT and BSCS!

Comment: @ShinRyujin - Since you, apparently, have just the one record, `VALUE ZERO` is fine. The only changes I recommend are those in the last two paragraphs. There is no need to alter the sequence of what you have by making other changes.